# How SSH's connection works?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I am learning how SSH works, the steps, the things that both client an server do to establish connection...
My doubt comes at the time of connect to the server:
If it is the first time you connect to the server, the client is asked to trust the connection, after that, the server's information is load on know_host for further connections, okay.
Now, if  I want to connect a server with IP 11.112.112.112, I have to use
`ssh 11.112.112.112` or `ssh user@11.112.112.112` ?
What is the difference between that 2 commands?
Why in the first command it is not necessary to specify a user?
In the second command, the fact that I am specifying a user means that the user must be create in the server?

Sorry for my bad English, and thank you.

Comment: If you don't specify the user, you'll be prompted by the server to enter the user's name

Comment: “ssh 11.112.112.112” assumes the current user

Comment: … the current user or whatever the config says (see `man 5 ssh_config`, keyword: `User`).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between both commands is simple: The first version ssh x.x.x.x will open a connection on the specified ssh port (22 is standardized, but can be changed for optimized security) and prompt the server to open a shell login. On this login you'll be asked to specify the user you would like to log in to and afterwards get prompted for that users password or (depending on if you have an ssh public key on that other machine) directly log you in as that user. The user that you want to login with must be a user that is already existing on the target machine.

With ssh user:x.x.x.x you simply skip the extra step of getting prompted for the username, by specifying it directly.

**Summarized:**
Whatever command you use, the user that you want to log in as needs to be an existing user on the target system. Nr.1 is just an extra prompt and Nr.2 is a shortcut that is usually used in f.e. programming (but can be ofc. used whenever you want), when a software needs to open an ssh connection to the target system.

Hope that sheds some light :)